# Rails class based on index value of in_groups_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following is intended to distribute array items into two columns.

```
<% @entitiquestions.in_groups_of(2, false) do |entitiquestions| %>
  <tr>
    <% entitiquestions.each do |entitiquestion| %>
      <td>
        <span data-tooltip class="hint--bottom hint--info" data-hint="<%= entitiquestion.question.query %>">
```

However, there is a class that should be set based on the index of the array item (if it is in fact an index...)

Can a condition be set somehow based on this position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index of the array item by using `each_with_index`, for example the following will give you a `row_index` variable which starts from `0` for the first row:

```
<% @entitiquestions.in_groups_of(2, false).each_with_index do |entitiquestions, row_index| %>
```

Likewise, you can get the column index with:

```
<% entitiquestions.each_with_index do |entitiquestion, column_index| %>
```

Now you have the exact position of the element within the table, so you can use a ternary operator to add a class. As an example, if you wanted to add the `highlight` class when the row is even you could do:

```
<span data-tooltip class="hint--bottom hint--info <%= 'highlight' if row_index.even? %>"
```

Here's a full example:

```
<table>
  <% @entitiquestions.in_groups_of(2, false).each_with_index do |entitiquestions, row_index| %>
    <tr>
      <% entitiquestions.each_with_index do |entitiquestion, column_index| %>
        <td>
          <span data-tooltip class="hint--bottom hint--info <%= 'highlight' if column_index.even? %>" data-hint="<%= entitiquestion.question.query %>">
            <%= entitiquestion.question.query %>
          </span>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: appreciation for the very complete answer, having double reference of indexing rows or columns.  Better insight